# Trouble converting an Access Function to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, ms-access

SQL learner here. I am having trouble converting a function built in Microsoft Access over the SQL Server.
Here is the Function as it appears in Access.

```
Function DatePop(DATE)

Dim DateMin As Date
Dim DateMax As Date

DateMin = "01/10"
DateMax = CDate(Now())

If (Format(DATE, "dd/mm") >= DateMin 

Or 

Format(DATE, "dd/mm") <= DateMax) 

Then DatePop = 1
    
Else DatePop = 0
    
End If

End Function
```

The goal of the function is to return a 1 if the date is after 1st October and before the current date. Otherwise return a 0.

Comment: What is this method trying to do? SQL Server and Access are *completely* different databases. Dates aren't text either and have no format. Whatever you want to do doesn't require converting anything to text.

Comment: In fact, it almost seems like what you want is just `IIF(date_col BETWEEN '20221001' AND GETDATE(),1,0)`, where `date_col` is a `date` column. Even that would be a bad idea in a WHERE clause because it would prevent the use of indexes. `WHERE date_col BETWEEN '20221001' AND GETDATE()` would use indexes. If `date_col` is a `datetime` or `datetime2` you'd have to modify the query to handle the time part. `

Comment: You still haven't explained what you really want

Comment: The goal of the function is to return a 1 if the date is after 1st October and before the current date. Otherwise return a 0.

Comment: Why do you want to return 1 or 0 instead of writing a condition? You're describing the code, not what the method is for. Access has [IIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) too. It also allows using BETWEEN. Filtering by a function's result is bad for performance in Access as well.

Comment: The function is used in a select statement in Access with WHERE theAccessfunction(DATE_COL)=1
So it filters the results only to include dates that meet the 1 result in the function.

Comment: That's a bad idea both in Access and SQL Server. Use `WHERE DATE_COL BETWEEN @date1 and @date2` instead

Comment: "01/10" is not a valid date.  As a human, I don't even understand what it is.  Is it Jan 10 or Jan 2010 or Oct 01 or Oct 2001???

Comment: Some developers love using functions because it makes the query look simple. However they often severely compromise performance so it is generally better to spell it out in the SQL where the engine can do what it is best at doing.

In T-SQL there is the concept of an Inline function which does not cause the same compromise but there is no equivalent in Access.

The other exception in T-SQL is the CLR function which is where you can write the function in a dotNET language so it gains the advantage of being compiled and performs like a native SQL function.

Comment: It not really a quesiton of love, it is a question of the work and time one has to endure during a migration project from Access to SQL server. I done more such migrations then I can remember, and this idea of moving some VBA functions used in the SQL to T-SQL functions? yes, it is a great idea from a migration point of view.  It not great for performance, but often that is a non issue!! The issue is world poverty and starving people to death. This question, this concept and this approach is a SOUND approach to Access to sql server migration projects as long as one is aware of the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so let’s re-write the VBA function as T-SQL.
Once such a function is created then that function can be used in T-SQL code (just like we did in VBA code). And such functions can now freely be used in any SQL Server SQL expressions. (Again, just like how such VBA functions could be used in JET/ACE SQL expressions).

So, there is a 1 to 1 symmetry in creating such functions in T-SQL, since then any VBA code converted to T-SQL code can now use that function you created. And same goes for any SQL you write server side, that function can be freely used in the SQL you write (again, just like writing SQL in Access and using VBA expressions in the SQL you write).

Also, there is still some "ambiguity" in your posted function. It looks to rely on the fact of a string compare that "ignores" the current year.  This is some what “high risk” since any change of regional settings on the desktop computer will quite much cause such code to break.

While you say "after" October, do you mean current year, or any date from any time and any year with the "month" after October? That looks like how that code works now, even if that was not your intention.

And don't use reserved words as variable names as they only seek to cause pain and suffering here.

So, let's first get this VBA code working correctly, or better stated, defined in such a way we can be 100% clear as to the logic. Thus when we spend out time and efforts, we thus are converting valid code to T-SQL.

So, based on what you have, then this looks to be the equivariant VBA code:

```
Public Function DatePop(nDate) As Integer

    Dim ToDay           As Date
    Dim iMonth          As Integer
    Dim iDay            As Integer
    
    iMonth = 10
    iDay = 1
    
    If IsNull(nDate) Then
       DatePop = 0
       Exit Function
    End If
    

    ToDay = CDate(Now())

    If (Month(nDate) >= iMonth) And (Day(nDate) > iDay) Then
        DatePop = 1
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If nDate <= ToDay Then
        DatePop = 1
        Exit Function
    End If
       
    DatePop = 0
    
End Function
```

As noted, you noted logic for "after" October, but do you mean ANY year, or only the current year for this logic?

And note how we forced (defined) the data type of the function return. Once again, we can't leave this up to the blowing wind.

Ok, so based on the above code, we can now convert and re-write the above VBA code into a T-SQL function that does the same thing.

So, this T-SQL should work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DatePop
(
    @nDate date
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @iMonth int
    DECLARE @iDay int
    DECLARE @ToDay date
    DECLARE @iResult int

    set @iResult = 0

    set @iMonth = 10
    set @iDay = 1
    set @ToDay = CAST(GETDATE() as date) -- date without time

    if month(@nDate) >= @iMonth AND day(@nDate) >= @iDay 
    BEGIN
        set @iResult = 1
    END

    if @nDate <= @ToDay
    BEGIN
       set @iResult = 1
    END

    RETURN @iResult

END
```

Once the above function is created? Then this should work like the VBA function. This includes use of the function in VBA code (or now T-SQL code), and that ALSO includes use of this function to be freely used in server-side T-SQL code you write.

The only noteworthy difference is that T-SQL functions MUST be prefixed with dbo. (The schema the function belongs to). So, when you cut + paste JET/ACE SQL into SQL server, then often the SAME SQL will work, but you have to edit the VBA function used in that SQL, and prefix with dbo.

Hence:

```
SELECT ID, HotelName, BookingDate, DatePop([BookingDate]) as MySeason
FROM Hotels
```

If you cut+ paste the above to SQL server, then it would become this:

```
SELECT ID, HotelName, BookingDate, dbo.DatePop([BookingDate]) as MySeason
FROM Hotels
```

Note in above how we have to "prefix" the DatePop function with "dbo.".